# SQL : Linked lists in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Have a structual question i dont know how to solve exactly.

Im doing an inventory system - where there should be support for multiple stores, each with their own item database, ex 100 stores with 50.000 itemnumbers.

The itemnumber database is global ( same itemnumbers for all stores ) - but since i need to keep track on stock count in each store, i assume i would need to create a local copy per shop, thats alot of tables and alot of redundant data.

But my headache is that for each inventory ( they count the complete shop from scrath ) - i need to add the new stockcount pr itemnumber ( and some result fields, corrected stock vs original stock etc. ) - and this is something that should be added each time they choose to do a complete restock/recount.

lets say the itemdatabase is :

itemno, description, total stock now

Then for a new inventory when its completed i need to add these 3 values to the record - if they chose to do ex. 200 inventory counts i would need 200 of these sets to be added per itemnumber :

inventorysession,total count, difference (total count - total count)

Since i have to be able to do this for each new restock/recount (inventory session), and keep the results for each as a history of events, i cannot ( i think ) in SQL add dynamic fields to the current table structure.

I could get it to work in my mind if i had some kind of linked list - where the linked list on the itemrecord would represent the sets of fields pr inventory-sessions - so instead of making a complete copy of the 50.000 records into another table for each inventory session, i would be able to extend the table throuh a linked list which would contain the 2.

Another option would be some kind of relational thing with several tables i guess, but that gets complicated and i worry about all the lookup's it would require.

Is it possible in a correct way to somehow use a linked list structure or this kinda of problem in a SQL database ? or would you advice me to use another database instead of SQL ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the structure for every new inventorysession? As you store the unique inventory session ID, you can just store all sessions in the same table, no? What is the requirement concerning cross-shop issues? Is there anything you need that cannot be handled in the shop's local database alone? Or are you looking for one central database, to which all stores connect?

Comment: But an inventory session would in theory have an added set of values for each and every itemnumber in the itemdatabase ? in my mind i would like to add them to the itemdatabase table pr record ? but since there can be many inventory sessions done, this structure is expanding with sets pr record one for each new inventory they do.

Comment: About the shop vs the general database. Its just that if i do a copy of the primary database with 50.000 records, into 100 shops each having a table with 50.000 records - thats alot of redundant data ( and there would be an idea in be able to maintain the itemdatabase as a centralized unit, so ex if they change the item description text they can do it in the master database of items, instead of having to change it for each and single shop )

Comment: The added set of values would come in another table, which would be keyed by inventory session ID and item number. This is the principle of master-detail in relational databases. About the central database, I understand that is what you would prefer. I agree that that is better if for the shops there is no technical issue to connect to it. If you could describe in more detail the exact properties you need, I could answer with a suggested database schema.

Comment: The central database concept i could do by using itemnumber and a reference to the record in the central database, that would work. but the lets say dynamic "horizontal expansion" of the per itemnumber expansion im trying to find out how i can do (instead of "vertical expansion") is causing me a headache.

Comment: i mean 50000 unique itemnumbers, true that most shops probably wouldnt have all 50K items in place, but in theory it would be possible that a store could have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think of the following central database schema:

```
stores
    id
    code
    name
    address
    ...

items
    id
    code
    name
    description
    barcode
    retail_price
    ...

stocks
    store_id
    item_id
    stock_count

inventories
    id
    inventory_date
    store_id

inventory_items
    inventory_id
    item_id 
    original_stock_count
    corrected_stock_count
```

So the stocks table would have references to the store where the stock is held and the item reference. Note that the details of the item are in the items table, which is independent from a store.

But in the stocks table you would have an item occurring multiple times, each time for a different store.

The inventories table has a record per inventory session, which is unique per store. This does not prevent from inventories to be taken for all stores at the same time, which would result in as many records, but leaves the flexibility to do one for one store only as well.

Then the inventory_items table adds the results of the inventory: per item the counts are logged.

Comment: Looks interesting let me check !

Comment: lets say there are 1 stock ( 50.000 items), and 1 inventory session (where they all count 50.000 items). then inventories would hold 50.000 records ?

Comment: You mean 1 store? Yes, then for one inventory session that would be right. In general you would have `#stores * #items` records per session.

Comment: Ok...hmm shouldnt i then split the Inventory into 2 tables, one that contains the header information ( like inventory id, and inventory_date, storeid ) and then another table with item,org stock, corrected stock that reference to the inventory id ?

Comment: I will try to make a litttle demo here, might be coming an array of sql questions though :) thanks alot  for your assistance

Comment: oh sorry thought i did accept it as answer. Didnt go so well though, but not your fault i think you are right but am struggling to get it working and getting a grasp of it. so will try some smaller questions of parts of the things that confuses me.